# PHP to post SQL command will only create and delete table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've created a PHP form to just run any query that I want.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,$_POST[myquery]);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This form will allow me to create and delete tables, as well as use the alter command. Though, it won't allow me to insert values or update things. Is there something wrong with my code or do I need to change settings with my db host? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: r u sure this is the complete code u have written for the above mentioned requirements?

Comment: please, write the queries you use to insert/update. Maybe they are written with invalid syntax or errors. Also note that anyone with access to the above script will be able to post any query (dropping tables, etc...)

Comment: I hope you realize this is the most insecure script ever, database-wise.

Comment: Does the user you've connected as have the ability to `WRITE`?

Comment: I used the command: insert into testtable values ('test1','test2') and the command works fine when I execute it from the actual myphpadmin. The user has the ability to write. The script will run in a panel that only I have access to, but even if someone gains access, I backup every file to my flash drive every night.

Comment: And what did `mysqli_error()` say now?

Comment: I've noticed that any command that requires the use of '' that is typed in my created query textarea, it causes it not to work, but I'm unsure how to fix that problem.

Comment: @mario the error says: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'test1\',\'test2\')' at line 1

Comment: I can't avoid the use of '' because it is required when using an insert statement. This isn't for my job, this is to setup a site to help other students learn. The point of it is to practice SQL commands. Dropping, altering, etc are all fine in this environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks valid, but it allows you to do everything, which is not secured.

restrict the privileges of 'user' to ALTER, CREATE and DROP only (for example. Remember that `DELETE` deletes data from a table whereas `DROP` delete the complete table definition and its data").

```
    GRANT CREATE , DROP , ALTER ON * . * TO 'the_user'@'the_host'
```

Grant only these rights to this user on your database (as you may have others):

```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db` . * TO 'the_user'@'the_host';
```

Finally, you could also analyse `$_POST[myquery]` before running it, to limit the possible commands and to avoid injection (addslaches)

Comment: When I submit a query, it adds slashes before every instance of ' so is there a way to prevent it from adding the \ before every '?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the host I am using places addslashes before every command that they deem dangerous. I used stripslashes($_POST[myquery]) and that fixed the problem! Thanks for everyone's help.